# i keep getting this error CS0029 could someone help me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the code is not working on the GameObject

```
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int rotateSpeed = 1;
    public int movementSpeed = 1;

    private Transform myTransform;
    public Transform target;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        target = go.transform;

        myTransform;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Rotate();
    }

    void Rotate ()
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(myTransform.position, target.position, Color.red);
    }
}
```

the error goes here

```
GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
target = go.transform;
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: CS0029 is a C# compilation error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'sourceType' to 'destinationType'"

Comment: Other than attempting to assign an array to a single object, you have this statement: `myTransform;`. What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 5):

`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")` returns an array of objects with type `GameObject`: See the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). Since your `GameObject go` is not an array, but a single `GameObject`, you're getting an error saying the compiler can't implicitly convert `GameObject[]` to `GameObject`.

If you only need one object, you may be looking for [GameObject.FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) which is called like this:

```c#
GameObject go = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
```